# ios 7.0.2 push notification not received

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification

I have implemented push notification in my iOS app. It works fine in `iOS 8.0(in iPhone 5s)` and in `iOS 7.1.1(in iPhone 5)`, but it fails to work in `iOS 7.0.2(in iPhone 4s)`.

Following is the code:

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
    {
        // iOS 8 Notifications
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
        // iOS < 8 Notifications
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
    UIViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"idHome"];
    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

I even get the `device token id` for all the versions.

Let me know where I am getting wrong. How do I solve this?

Comment: check iPhone 4s setting->notification view your application is appear there ?

Comment: check internet connection if all is ok then restart your device also.

Comment: @Rushabh- checked it, internet works fine. Settings also has the app name.